# MailChimp API & AJAX adding a hidden field

Tags: ajax, forms, mailchimp, hidden-field

I've currently a simple plain newsletter subscription form in the footer of our website with only a email text field. We want to know on which language version our subscribers fill in our form. (domain.com/**nl**/.**de**/.**it** etc).

I've added a hidden field that gets the value of the current language.

```
    <li>
    <label for="footer-newsletter-input"><?php __("nav.newsletter.youremail"); ?></label>
    <input type="text" id="footer-newsletter-input" class="font-MuseoSans100 validate" data-validationtype="email">
     </li>

     <li class="hidden">
     <input type="text" id="footer-newsletter-input-language" class="font-MuseoSans100" value="<?php echo isset(Language::$short) ? Language::$short : 'en'; ?>">
     </li>
```

**This is working.**

Our current initNewsletter: function() is as follows:

```
    initNewsletter: function() {

        $(document).on('submit', '#newsletter_form', function(e){

            e.preventDefault();
            $('#newsletter-holder p.error').hide();

            if($(this).hasClass('loading')) return;

            var form = $(this),
                valid = checkForm(form),
                email = $('#footer-newsletter-input').val();
            ??? shortlangcode = $('#footer-newsletter-input-language'); ???



            if(valid) {

                form.addClass('loading');

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: '/support/subscribe',
                    data: 'email=' + email, ??????
                    success: function(data){

                        form.removeClass('loading');

                        data = $.parseJSON(data);
                        if(data.status && data.status === 'error') {
                           $('#newsletter-holder').append('<p class="error font-MuseoSans100">' + window.globalTranslations.newsletter_error + '</p>');
                        } else {
                           $('#newsletter-inputs').fadeOut(150, function(){
                               $('#newsletter-thanks').show();
                           });

                        }


                    },
                    error: function(){
                        $('#newsletter-holder').append('<p class="error font-MuseoSans100">' + window.globalTranslations.newsletter_error + '</p>');
                    }
                });

            }

        });

    },
```

And the controller looks as follows:

```
    public function subscribe() {

    // API KEY
    $apikey = '????';
    $listid = '????';

    $MailChimp = new MailChimp($apikey);
    $result = $MailChimp->call('lists/subscribe', array(
        'id'                => $listid,
        'email'             => array('email'=>$_POST['email']),
        //'merge_vars'        => array('FNAME'=>$_POST['fname'], 'LNAME'=>$_POST['lname']),
        'double_optin'      => true,
        'update_existing'   => true,
        'replace_interests' => false,
        'send_welcome'      => false,
    ));

    echo json_encode($result);

}
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: I cant figure out how to send the value of input with id="footer-newsletter-input-language" to mailchimp. I guess i need to declare the value in  initNewsletter: function() and send it with Ajax post. (I've added ???? on the place i think it needs to be added) And then the controller need to be updated to include merge_vars =>('CNTRCODE' => $_POST['cntrcode']),

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add a `name` parameter to your form field. So it could become this:

```
<input type="text" id="footer-newsletter-input-language" name="language" class="font-MuseoSans100" value="<?php echo isset(Language::$short) ? Language::$short : 'en'; ?>">
```

Then in your controller, you access it like this:

```
$result = $MailChimp->call('lists/subscribe', array(
    'id'                => $listid,
    'email'             => array('email'=>$_POST['email']),
    'merge_vars'        => array('CNTRCODE'=>$_POST['language']),
    'double_optin'      => true,
    'update_existing'   => true,
    'replace_interests' => false,
    'send_welcome'      => false,
));
```

You'll have to make sure that a merge field named CNTRCODE is created within mailchimp for that list.

Comment: Added the lines but does not seem to work. I think i need to add the language also in the initNewsletter: function() to declare it and send it.

Comment: What do you mean "does not seem to work"? Is the user being subscribed at all? CNTRCODE missing? Have you looked at the raw request / response yet?